# Word VBA macro fails to create backup of File MRU registery key

Tags: vba

I'm very much a novice with respect to VBA. A few years ago the Most Recent Used list (including the pinned files) would become corrupted after a bit of research I found the following which created a backup of the File MRU every time word was opened (see the following)

```
    Sub AutoExec()
' Create a backup of the File Mru registry key when word is opened.
' MsgBox "Greetings", vbOKOnly, "Greetings"
    Shell Environ("WINDIR") & "\SYSTEM32\reg.exe export " & Chr(34) & _
        "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Word\User MRU\" & _"LiveId_D6CF29E4B97077D0A76F7336D24E2C0D2CC2C35617F8F98E36F6D833C8F7EF13\File MRU" & _ 
Chr(34) & " C:\BackupFileMRU\Word-file-mru_" & Format(Now, "yyyy-MM-dd") & ".reg /Y"
End Sub
```

This worked and I'd often use one of the reg files from the backup to restore the MRU list. This past July (07/18/22) it stopped working .... I have no idea why. I tried to find a solution and eliminate the errors and created the following.

```
    Sub AutoExec()
' Create a backup of the File Mru registry key when word is opened.
' MsgBox "Greetings", vbOKOnly, "Greetings"
 MsgBox Environ("WINDIR") & "\SYSTEM32\reg.exe export " & _
       "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Word\User MRU\LiveId_D6CF29E4B97077D0A76F7336D24E2C0D2CC2C35617F8F98E36F6D833C8F7EF13\File MRU" & _
       " C:\BackupFileMRU\Word-file-mru_" & Format(Now, "yyyy-MM-dd") & ".reg /Y "

   Environ ("WINDIR") & "\SYSTEM32\reg.exe export " & _
       "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Word\User MRU\LiveId_D6CF29E4B97077D0A76F7336D24E2C0D2CC2C35617F8F98E36F6D833C8F7EF13\File MRU" & _
       " C:\BackupFileMRU\Word-file-mru_" & Format(Now, "yyyy-MM-dd") & ".reg /Y "
End Sub
```

The MsgBox displays what I think is correct but the code itself does NOT create my backup. Obviously, I've done something wrong but I know not what the heck it is!

The original code included "Shell" just before "Environ" but in my revised code, it gives me an error. I've attempted to find a VBA solution but encountered a vast number of internet pages that leave me totally confused and so far everything I've tried does not work.

**Update 2022 1011** - I have verified that the reg path is correct and it does contain the MRU info.

**Update 2022 1017** - I recently discovered that my antivirus, Bitdefender, is blocking the macro because the macro is attempting to do something with the Registry. I've contacted Bitdefender support and now waiting for a reply.

Comment: In the lower script, at least the `Shell`-command is missing. There is, btw, no need to add the Windows-path, simply call `reg export`. And you should check if the Reg-Path is still valid, maybe the ID changed?

Comment: I may be doing multiple things wrong (dumb user!!)

Comment: I assume I did not enter the correct format but I don't know what is missing.

I did verify that the key is present and I have entered the address correctly.
How do I add images to this post?

Comment: OH darn, my full response is not appearing

Comment: Another attempt to get my response posted, I entered the following

Shell Environ("WINDIR") & "\SYSTEM32\reg.exe export " & _
       "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Word\User MRU\LiveId_D6CF29E4B97077D0A76F7336D24E2C0D2CC2C35617F8F98E36F6D833C8F7EF13\File MRU" & _
       " C:\BackupFileMRU\Word-file-mru_test.reg /Y "

This gives me a run time error of 5, I click on the debug button and I see the above statement highlited.

Comment: Please don't post this as comment, update your question and put your updated code there. Also, add the exact error message - not everyone knows all runtime codes by heart, and there are errors that can show different error messages for the same number.